# Use of files in the Tasks Folder in Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi i am new to ruby on rails and am currently working on a project ..

I am a bit confused bout the use of the use of the two files given below..

The below file is cron_tasks.rb found in Tasks folder of the application

```
 class CronTasks

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  perform
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def self.perform(method)
      with_logging method do
        self.new.send(method)
      end
    end

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  with_logging
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def self.with_logging(method, &block)
      log("Starting...", method)

      time = Benchmark.ms do
        yield block
      end

      log("Completed in (%.1fms)" % [time], method)
    end

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  log
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def self.log(message, method = nil)
      now = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      Rails.logger.info "#{now} %s#%s - #{message}" % [self.name, method]
    end

    ############# Instance Methods ####################

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  calculate_fines
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def calculate_fines
        LmsTasks.calculate_fines
    end

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  overdue_alert
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def overdue_alert
        LmsTasks.overdue_alert      
    end

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  due_alert
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def due_alert
        LmsTasks.due_alert      
    end      

end
```

Also the other file is Lov_helper.rb which is found in the Helpers folders

```
module LovHelper

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  getLov - Get a list of values for a particular LOV type
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def self.getLov(lov_type)
        lovs = LovValue.unscoped
        lovs = lovs.select('lov_values.id, lov_value')
        lovs = lovs.joins(:lov_name)
        lovs = lovs.where('lov_names.name = ? ', lov_type)
        lovs = lovs.order('sequence asc')
        lovs.all

        return lovs     
    end

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  getValue - Get the value pertaining to a particular LOV Value id
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def self.getValue(lov_value_id)
        lov = LovValue.find(:all,
                                :select => 'lov_value',
                                :conditions => ['id = ? ', lov_value_id]).first
        return lov.lov_value
    end

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    #  getLovNames - Get a list of LOV names
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def self.getLovNames
        lov_names = LovName.all
        return lov_names
    end

end
```

Can anyone tell me the significance of the below files and why they are used.

Comment: LovHelper seems specific to your project. CronTasks seems to help with logging. I'm not sure how we could help you with this.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott are they compulsary to put ..and if i dont put it will the application give any error...

Also what is recommended to use these files or not or use according to you

Comment: @What are the default files in the folders Task and why are they used can u give me any idea...

Comment: There are no default files in the tasks folder. You add rake tasks to your project to perform offline tasks in your application. background: http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Thank you for the help you have provided Much appreciated